# Search Limited to Categories Not Working

Tags: search

I am trying to limit my search to specific categories. my code is as below

searchform.php

```
        <form id="searchform" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>" method="get" class="form-stacked">

            <fieldset>
                <div class="clearfix">
                <div class="input-append">
                <input type="search" name="s" id="s" placeholder="<?php _e("Search","bonestheme"); ?>" value="<?php the_search_query(); ?>" />
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"><i class="icon-search"></i></button>

                <div id="searchOptions">
                <input type="radio" value="all" name="search_type" id="searchOptionsAll" checked="checked" /> <label for="searchOptionsAll">Search All</label> &nbsp; &nbsp;
                <input type="radio" value="books" name="search_type" id="searchOptionsBooks" /> <label>Books</label>&nbsp; &nbsp;
                <input type="radio" value="blogposts" name="search_type" id="searchOptionsArticles" /> <label>Articles</label>&nbsp; &nbsp;
                </div>          
                </div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>


        </form>
```

functions.php

```
function SearchByFilter($query) {
  if ($query->is_search or $query->is_feed) {
    //everything
    if($_GET['search_type'] == "all") {
      $query->set('post_type', 'post');
    }
    //recipes
    elseif($_GET['search_type'] == "books") {
      $query->set('post_type', 'post');
      $recicategories=  get_categories('child_of=47'); 
      foreach($recicategories as $recicategory) { 
        $cat_ids = wp_list_pluck($recicategories,'term_id');
      }
      $ccatsearch2 =  implode(',',$cat_ids);
      $query->set('cat',$ccatsearch2 );
    }
    //articles
    elseif($_GET['search_type'] == "blogposts") {
      $query->set('post_type', 'post');
      $blogcategories=  get_categories('child_of=42'); 
      foreach($blogcategories as $blogcategory) { 
        $cat_ids = wp_list_pluck($blogcategories,'term_id');
      }
      $ccatsearch =  implode(',',$cat_ids);
      $query->set('cat',$ccatsearch );
    }
  }
  return $query;
}
//jump into the loop and arrange our results before they're returned
add_filter('pre_get_posts','SearchByFilter');
```

somehow , above code is not working and with my limited knowledge, I am not able to understand where I am making the mistake.

Please help.

Regards

Comment: "code is not working" is not much of a trouble ticket. _Exactly_ what isn't working? What is the result you want and what is the result you get?

Comment: The code does not limit search result to specific category, it always shows all results.

Comment: Specific to the situation, try using [WP Custom Field Search](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-custom-fields-search/) plugin for a nice customized search functionality. I've used it in [here](http://www.sultanstationery.com)